# Not able to cover Catch block using Junits

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to cover my Utility class using JUnits but i am not able to cover **catch block** since 1 day and i am not understanding what is problem for not covering this catch block can some one help me..

### Class

```
public class CustomStringConverter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomStringConverter.class);

    private CustomStringConverter() {}

    public static String objectToJsonString(Object obj) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("CustomStringConverter.objectToString: Generic Exception", e);
        }
        return AccessIdConstants.EMPTY;
    }

}
```

### Test class

```
public class CustomStringConverterTest {

    private static final String NAME = "name";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private static final long ID = 1L;

    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Rule
    public RuleChain ruleChain = RuleChain.outerRule(collector).around(expectedException);

    @Test
    public void objectToJsonStringTest() throws Exception {
        TestHelper testHelper = new TestHelper();
        testHelper.setId(ID);
        testHelper.setName(NAME);
        CustomStringConverter.objectToJsonString(testHelper);
    }

    @Test
    public void objectToJsonStringTest_Exception() throws Exception {
        // Assert
        expectedException.expect(Exception.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\"name\":\"john\",\"age\":22,\"class\":\"mca\"}";
        mapper.readValue(json, TestExceptionHelper.class);
        CustomStringConverter.objectToJsonString(new Object());
    }

    class TestExceptionHelper {

        String title;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }

    static class TestHelper {

        String name;
        long id;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You do not throw exception in your method, remove catch block in `objectToJsonStringTest_Exception()` or rethrow in catch.

Comment: Can you suggest me with code

Comment: Use Mockito and any other Mock library.

Comment: We can't use mockito for static methods

Comment: We can't use mockito for static methods

Comment: Would this not be covered with a test for `objectToJsonString(null)`?

Comment: No it's not working I already try that

Comment: @Krish ok, then what cases are you expecting could possibly throw an exception? If you can't trigger code, perhaps it's not necessary.

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions only thing is not able to cover the catch block

Comment: Is this possible to cover catch block?

Comment: Is this possible to cover catch block?

Answer (score -2):

```
CustomStringConverter.objectToJsonString(new Object());
```

Use null instead of new Object() in above statement, you should get NullPointerException

```
CustomStringConverter.objectToJsonString(null);
```

Comment: Try using mockito to change behaviour of method for testing purposes

Comment: Mockito is unable to mock static methods